# Merge Duplicates based on column?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

Here's my situation -

```
In[9]: df
Out[9]: 
    fruit  val1  val2
0  Orange     1     1
1  orANGE     2     2
2   apple     3     3
3   APPLE     4     4
4   mango     5     5
5   appLE     6     6

In[10]: type(df)
Out[10]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

How do remove case-insensitive duplicates such that resulting `fruit` will be all lower with `val1` as sum of each `val1`s and `val2` as sum of each`val2`s

Expected result:

```
  fruit    val1 val2
0 orange    3    3
1 apple     13   13
2 mango     5    5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In two steps:

```
df['fruit'] = df['fruit'].map(lambda x: x.lower())

res = df.groupby('fruit').sum()

res    
#         val1  val2
# fruit             
# apple     13    13
# mango      5     5
# orange     3     3
```

And to recover your structure:

```
res.reset_index()
```

---

as per the comment, the lower casing can be accomplished in a more straight forward way like this:

```
df['fruit'] = df['fruit'].str.lower()
```

Comment: Instead of the `map`, you could use `df['fruit'].str.lower()` here.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.fruit.str.lower()).sum().reset_index()` concisely .